# Javascript Functional Programming

Tags: javascript, function

I'm confused on why one is returning me the sum while the other one is just returning the list.

This correctly returns the output `10`

```
function sum(){
     var arrays = [1,2,3,4].reduce(function (total, num) {

       return total + num;
   })
    console.log(arrays);
}
```

This however, returns `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and not 10.

```
function sum(){
    var arrays = [1,2,3,4];
    arrays.reduce(function (total, num) {

      return total + num;  
  })
  console.log(arrays);
}
```

At first I thought it's where I was declaring the `var arrays` so I tried moving it out of the function and also tried not declaring it `var`. However for this one I'm still not getting 10.

What's the difference between the two that I'm not getting the correct output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second function you are ignoring the return value from the `reduce` method. It will correctly calculate the sum, but you don't use it.

Assign the result to the variable as in the first function:

```
array = arrays.reduce(function (total, num) {
  return total + num;  
});
```

---

However, having the result in the same variable as where the array was makes the code somewhat confusing. You should avoid having a variable change meaning in the middle of the code, so you can use a different variable for the result:

```
function sum(){
    var arrays = [1,2,3,4];
    var result = arrays.reduce(function (total, num) {
      return total + num;
  });
  console.log(result);
}
```

---

Side note: The term [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) is used for languages that are based on functional expressions instead of variable state. Just using a function doesn't mean that you are using functional programming.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the assignment, which is returned by the `reduce`:

```
function sum() {
  var arrays = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  arrays = arrays.reduce(function(total, num) {
  //-----^
    return total + num;
  })
  console.log(arrays);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In first,
when the function return the value i.e. `10` it is getting stored in `var arrays` and you are printing it.

whereas,
In second,
You declared the `var arrays` and give it the value `[1,2,3,4]` then funtion is called, the returned value is not getting stored anywhere and at last you are simply printing the `var arrays` which is `[1,2,3,4]`